# Daylight time saving aware conversion of timestamps in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

Given a timestamp without time zone (e.g. `2018-03-12 09:30:00`) AND the timezone `EST5EDT`, the goal is to parse the data returning a datetime object that is time zone AND daylight saving aware.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

datetime(2018, 3, 8, 9, 30, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('EST5EDT')).astimezone(pytz.utc)
# returns:
# datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 8, 14, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)

datetime(2018, 3, 12, 9, 30, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('EST5EDT')).astimezone(pytz.utc)
# returns:
# datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 12, 14, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
# BUT should return (second Sunday of march the daylight saving changes by 1 hour):
# datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 12, 13, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never set `tzinfo` directly when creating datetimes. Always use the `localize()` method of the timezone (see the note at the top of http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

```
pytz.timezone('EST5EDT').localize(
    datetime(2018, 3, 12, 9, 30)
).astimezone(pytz.utc)
```